# static initialization of a class in C#

Tags: c#, class, struct, initialization

I have a need to convert/upgrade my data structure struct to a class and have a question:
Can I statically initiate my class like the struct? If so, any guidance of how to do it would be highly appreciate.
Below is the definition of my struct:

```
typedef struct t
{
   struct t *next;
   int otherfield;
} T

T r1[]={{0,1},{0,2}};
T s1[]={{r1,3},{0,4}};
```

My converted class looks like

```
class T
{
  class T next;
  int otherfield;
}
List<T> r1;
List<T> s1;
```

How do I statically initiate r1, s1. Standard initialization thru a constructor may not work as I have hundred of these struct and they were all initialized statically.

Thanks,

Comment: What is `class T next;` supposed to be?

Comment: can you provide an example of "static intialization" you're talking about ?

Comment: It would be really nice if your code was actually valid C#.

Comment: @codesparkle: They are C# code

Comment: @SimpleCoder: "class T next" is the next instance that is a class T.

Comment: @Tigran: I would like to initialize the list like I initialize the array r1, r2 in struct.

Comment: In its current state, no, it is not valid C#. Should `next` be a method or a property? I think you meant `T Next()`.

Comment: @user1205746 let me tell you a thing or two: C# doesn't have a `typedef` keyword, the keyword `class` can't be used as a field modifier, and the `[]` come after the array type, not the identifier; and that's not even all, there are more syntax errors. So **don't tell me that this is supposed to be C#.**

Comment: @codesparkle: I apologize for not being clear. Yes, the original block with typedef is not in C# (they are in C) and that is the reason why I would like to transform it to C#. I hope the 2nd block is C# as I think C# does allow us to declare a class within a class. I maybe wrong but the compiler did not complaint. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @SimpleCoder The first block is not in C# but I think the 2nd block is. I think C# allow us to have a class within a class since the compiler does not complaint. Now, if the code works as it supposed or intended to, that is a different question. I need to do further testing to check, but at least, the compiler did not frown at it.

Comment: I know the first block is C++ or similar, but the second is still not C#. You *can* define nested classes, but `class T next;` is **not** valid C#. That line is half class definition and half field declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do the following?

```
class T
{
    public T next;
    public int otherfield;
    public T( T next, int otherfield )
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.otherfield = otherfield
    }
}

T[] r1 = new T[]{ new T( null, 1 ), new T( null, 2 ) };
T[] s1 = new T[]{ new T( r1[0], 3 ), new T( null, 4 ) };
```

***Edit***: if you want to do it with a List then you could do the following:

```
List< T > r1 = new List< T >( new T[]{ new T( null, 1 ), new T( null, 2 ) } );
List< T > s1 = new List< T >( new T[]{ new T( r1[0], 3 ), new T( null, 4 ) } );
```

Comment: Thank Goz. I have thought about that. I guess I have to go with this approach if there are no alternatives. I prefer to use List<T> but not sure if I am crazy.

Comment: The list initialization also works directly, without the detour through an array, since you can use a collection initializer.

Comment: Thanks, Goz. I will give it a swirl and see how that turns out. Thank you for your help! Very much appreciated.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I prefer what you mentioned earlier "without a detour through an array" since it appear to be simpler and more elegant. But could you be more specific? Sorry, I am pretty new to collection initializer stuff as I come from a C/C++ background.

Comment: @user1205746: [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) basically work like array initializers. `List T l1 = new List<T> { new T(null, 1), new T(null, 2) };`. You can also use objects initializers: `new T { next = null, otherfield = 2 }`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much Oliver! I think that is what I am looking for!!! Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: Use a list and give the array as parameter to the constructor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Goz: Your suggestion works! It looks more complex than the C version but it appears to work. Thanks!